# How to change vertical slide movement to horizontal movement in jQuery slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, slider

I have a slider at main page and in its 2nd slide there is another slider in it which is vertical slider.
I want to change its vertical slide movement to horizontal movement.Basically i want to change its direction.
Here is the live link [Slidedeck](http://www.slidedeck.com/).

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at jQuery UI accordion...

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Accordion